# Upload data from other sources to a stream table in correct data types with Python API

Tags: sql-insert, dolphindb, data-transform

I need to insert high frequency data received by websocket into a DolphinDB stream table. The data is a list of strings, i.e. [string, string, ..... , string]. Any efficient way to insert such data into a stream table with automatic data type conversion?

I couldn't find the function to automatically recognize the strings and convert them to the corresponding type when inserting the strings.

The received data is as follows. Is there any way to process the strings?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to upload the data:

1.(Recommended) Convert the strings to the correct data types in your Python client first. And then insert the data into a DolphinDB table with the class `MultithreadedTableWriter`, or upload data first and append them to the target table with `tableAppender`.

2.Insert data to DolphinDB and then manually specify the data types when inserting data to the target table. You can refer to the following script:

```
s = "insert into tb values(%s, %s, %s)" % (2, "222", "dd")
script = """t = table(1000:0,`id`date`ticker`price, [INT,DATE,SYMBOL,DOUBLE])
share t as tglobal"""
s.run(script)
def createDemoDict():
    return {'id': ['1', '2', '2', '3'],
            'date': np.array(['2019-02-04', '2019-02-05', '2019-02-09', '2019-02-13'], dtype='datetime64[D]'),
            'ticker': ['AAPL', 'AMZN', 'AMZN', 'A'],
            'price': ['22.0', '3.5', '21.0', '26.0']}

tb = pd.DataFrame(createDemoDict())
s.upload({'tb': tb})
s.run("tableInsert(tglobal,(select int(id), date(date) as date, ticker, double(price) from tb))")
print(s.run("tglobal"))
```

3.Concatenate strings in the in an `insert into` statement, then `run()` the statement with Python API. For example:

```
"insert into tb values(%s, %s, %s)" % (s1, s2, s3)
```

Comment: too many copy for insert.  what is efficient way?